# Comparing an array to two static values

Tags: java

So I am just doing something simple. I made a simple Java program where you enter your guess for what the roll will be which is stored in an array and then compared to two  numbers generated randomly. So my question is how would I do  the comparison of the array against the two number without referencing  the exact index (i.e. not array[0]=number[1])? I am doing this mostly to figure out how array work. Also why is the else erroring?

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int [] guess= new int [2];
    System.out.print("Enter " + guess.length + " values: ");
    for (int i=0; i<guess.length;i++)
        guess[i] = input.nextInt();

    method(guess);



}

public static String method(int [] that){
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6);
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6);  
    for (int i =0;i<that.length;i++){
        if(that[i]==number1 and that[i]+1==number2)
        {
            return "You got it";
        }
        else
        { 
            return "try again";
        }//end else
    } //end for
}//end method
```

Comment: I think there are better ways to learn about arrays than this. Check out some Java books. Also `that[i]+1==number2` is supposed to be `that[i+1]==number2`.

Comment: Correct your formating - especially indentation - and the syntax errors will be obvious.

Comment: I have a few but if you have any recommendations for books let me know

Comment: Look into the Random class. It's more appropriate, here, than Math.random(); it can actually generate ints without a cast.

Comment: Replace 'and' with '&&' and seems like your logic is not correct. Study the java basic first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write `and` like that , if you want to `AND` two conditions write `&&`. Also in your `if` condition I think you mean to increment your `index that[i+1]==number2` , you were incrementing the random number itself. So your if condition would look like:-

```
 if(that[i]==number1 && that[i+1]==number2)
        {
            return "You got it";
        }
    else{
      ..
         }
```

Also want to add that you output `You got it` or `try again` will not be visible to user, since you are just calling the method `method(guess);` from `main()` which returns a `String` but does not do anything with returned `String`. You have to write it like this to make the ouput visible on console.

```
System.out.println(method(guess));
```

Comment: last question and I think I got it do you know why it would say fails to return at the end

Comment: @user3685048, there is no return statement at end of the method. You must put return statement at end of the method

Comment: It will work now, the function was having errors so it could not return any value from if or else.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the array contains the element or not like this

```
Arrays.asList(that).contains(number1)
```

It will return true if the array contains the element else as false

Comment: do I have to import something to get that to work because it doesn't recognize "arrays"

Answer (score 0):

if you want comparison of the array against the two number without referencing the exact index then the first thing that you can do is use enhance for loop to avoid indexing of array like this

```
for(int number: that){
  // do your comparison while iterating numbers in that(array) as "number" 
}
```